# Wowza Streaming Engine How to save a back up version of app configuration, user name and password

Tags: video-streaming, wowza

I have just install a Wowza Streaming Engine using docker container.
I am wordering about how the Wowza store app configuration, user name and password?

Is it possible to save a back up version of these configurations?
I want to keep the configuration for next deploying.
I have already redeploy the engine and these configurations have been lose.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a script to synchronize your `conf/` and other important directories to S3 or another cloud provider on a cron schedule.

When creating a new docker image, include a step to restore that configuration, copying from S3.